# CSS background for entire half of '.row' inside '.col-md-6'

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am trying to set a background for half of a row as shown in the image [image: Section Image] with the grey representing the background image.

But when I set the background of the second .col-md-6, It only sets the background for that and leaves out the padding. I understand that is how it is meant to be. But I was hoping for suggestions on how to go about this while achieving the layout I want ( shown in the image). I am using Bootstrap 4.

So far my code structure is:

```
<section>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <!-- LEFT SECTION -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="container">
         TITLE AND CONTENT LEFT
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- RIGHT SECTION -->
    <div id="right" class="col-md-6">
      <div class="container">
         TITLE AND CONTENT LEFT
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

My CSS is:

```
#right{
 background-size:cover;
 background-image: imageUrl;
}

//For overlay over image
#right:before{
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 left:0; right: 0; 
 top: 0; bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(195,68,86,0.2);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your CSS?

Comment: Your CSS is important here.

Comment: Which bootstrap version do you use? And please provide some css.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I have added that I am using Bootstrap 4 and  some CSS

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Bootstrap. The .row class has margins related to its parent. And since the .col-md-6 is inside the .row element, it has to respect its boundaries (thats how HTML and CSS works), except if you make the position of the .col-md-6 class "absolute", but that's not the default behavior with out-of-the-box bootstrap.

You could consider using .row-fluid, it changes the margins, but if you want to keep that padding, you will need to make some custom css to make the padding inside the .col-md-6 classes.

And remember:
margin > border > padding

The background is applied only inside the borders.

Answer (score 0):

Use class container-fluid and following css.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

CSS

```
.row {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.col-6 {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.row div.col-6:last-child {
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/47448/

Answer (score 0):

The easiesst way:

```css
section{position: relative;min-height: 200px;}
section:before{content:"";position: absolute;left:50%; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;background: rgba(195,68,86,0.2);}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <!-- LEFT SECTION -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">

         LEFT

    </div>

    <!-- RIGHT SECTION -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">

         RIGHT

    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```